# what is the 1 of N model implementation for GIC600

Tags: interrupt-handling, armv8

Working on GIC 600 for 1 of N model for SPI. I have 3 question below

1. Suppose we have 4 PE. Suppose first core is busy with higher priority task and others are in sleep. what is the decision of GIC?
2. At what condition the interrupt is divert from one core to another core
3. Can we route interrupt to specific PE in 1 of N model

Thank you in advance

Explore GIC600 spec but not clear about how GIC behave in different scenarios